# Why does $k \to np$?

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence

I am trying to understand the DeMoivre-Laplace Theorem in [this page](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem.html).

There's a section called **Proof**, where k is defined as $k=np + \sqrt{npq}x$. Then it says that "From this definition we have the approximations $k \to np$" when $n \to \infty$ and I get stuck here. I don't understand why $k \to np$.

Comment: As $n \to \infty$, the square root $\sqrt{n}$ becomes negligible compared to the linear term.

Comment: It's a sloppiness on the page you cite.  They write $k\to np$ but mean $k/n\to p$ or $k\sim np$.  Both $k$ and $np$ tend to infinity in the DeMoivre-Laplace theorem, and, strictly speaking $k\to np$ is a no-no.  But one that good mathematicians use informally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $np+(\sqrt{npq})x=np\left(1+\frac{(\sqrt{npq})x}{np}\right)=np(1+O(1/\sqrt n))$. Thus, as $n\to\infty$, we have $k\sim np$. In particular, all the author of the article means is that $k\to\infty$ at exactly the same rate as $np$ as $n\to\infty$. These types of arguments are particularly useful when needing to work with asymptotics rather than exact values; it gives us an easy way to bound quantities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But $np+x\sqrt{np}=\sqrt{np}(\sqrt{np}+x)$ and if you take the limit when $n \to \infty$, then you get $\infty * \infty = \infty$. What do you think about it?

Comment: @roy212: Yes? $k/np\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. This means $k\approx np$ or more specifically,  $k\sim np$. Both tend to infinity with $n$, and $k$'s rate of convergence to $\infty$ is exactly the same as $np$.

Comment: If both tend to infinity. Why is it wrong when I say that "$np+x\sqrt{np}=\sqrt{np}(\sqrt{np}+x)$ and if you take the limit when $n \to \infty$, then you get $\infty * \infty = \infty$"?

Comment: @roy212: it isn't wrong, it just doesn't provide as much information. As the comment underneath your post and my answer both state, $k\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and $np\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. What is relevant is that $\frac{k}{n}\to p$ as $n\to\infty$. This contains very important information about how $k$ behaves for large values of $n$. What you have written only says that $k\to\infty$ but doesn't give a rate of convergence (or divergence, if you prefer to think of it that way).

Comment: @roy212: Beyond my answer, I don't think so... clearly $1/\sqrt{n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. This leaves a $p\cdot(1)=p$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thank you so much!